How to name historical places whose names have been lost in a historical novel
For example, the original name that its builders gave to the Inca citadel of Machu Picchu has been lost. Its current name was probably given to it by American explorer Hiram Bingham in 1911. So, in a story set during Inca settlement or before Bingham named the ruins, how should I name the city?
What's the best practice to name a historical place whose historical name has been lost?

Is your question about describing a country (e.g. what the landscape and culture are like etc.) or about naming a country (e.g. "Germany" or "Deutschland"), and is it about describing or naming a historical country (e.g. medieval Germany) or a fictional country (e.g. Tolkien's Middle Earth)?

@Ben country and places like historical site such as Machu Picchu that we don't know its original name. For example if I were an explorer in year 1000 and found Machu Picchu, or if I was the one who build it, it will be weird if I call it as such. But I still want my reader to know that I'm referring to Machu Picchu

I have edited your question to clarify it. You can edit it further, if you want.

My theory is that is that your story is already translating native languages to English (or some modern language).
The language of the Incan empire that build Machu Picchu is "Quechua", and although there are still native Quechuan speakers, if you are not writing in Quechua; then your book is an English translation of what the characters are saying; to make the story accessible to readers.
And "Machu Picchu" is the English translation of that city's name. (Originally, "Machu Pikchu" in Quechuan spelling; "Machu" means old or ancient; and "Pikchu" means "mountain" or "peak". The current name was not given by an American explorer; it is in the Incan language and was probably just reported that way, slightly misspelt).
If you want readers to recognize it, call it Machu Picchu.
The same goes for any other landmark. Your character dialogue and place names are translations to modern English from a language most readers would find incomprehensible -- Old English from 1500 years ago would be incomprehensible to modern speakers; if that is our setting we must translate to modern.
The same applies to your story. See dialogue as a translation to modern English. That doesn't mean their ideas and beliefs must be modernized, just the language they use to express them, to make that accessible to modern readers.

In an effort to broaden the topic from specifically Machu Picchu:
Generalize the language
Use commonly understood words to generalize structures, districts, and features: the City, the river wall, the narrow gate.
In normal conversation I don't use official names for the places in my own city. The business center is called 'the city'. Shopping is at my local market, called "the store" or potentially "the corner store" to differentiate from another market that's bigger and further away.
In my day-to-day life I almost never call the place I live 'New York City', certainly not to other people who live here. Smaller neighborhoods might be mentioned, but their boundaries, where one area becomes another are blurry and subjective. Outside of some specific context like mailing a letter or voting, my definition of a place won't perfectly match with someone else's.
Personalize through perspective
Use the perspective of various characters within the story to build the idea of a multi-facetted place. There's an old parable of 3 blind men who each touch a different part of an elephant and describe a different creature. Draw on that idea to build up a composite of the location as a living community full of dichotomy and contradiction.
A farmer who only experiences the city's streets and marketplaces, a guard who sees the city in terms of 'outsiders' and defendable walls, an official who has an abstracted idea how the city functions as the cultural center of a larger territory... Each would have a different idea of this place, the boundaries are different, and the importance is different.
Each would have different associations and emotional reactions to the name of the place. None of the inhabitants would view the location as a single monolith the way a historian would.
Signal Fact vs Fiction
Popular fantasy novels are often set in real locations. The factuality of a description can be signaled through official (historic-sounding) names, while the fanciful parts can be signaled through in-world logic. Harry Potter's wizard adventure diverges from the normal world at King's Cross Station – a real life location – on Platform 9 3/4 – a description too fanciful to take seriously. King's Cross sounds realistic, even to a non-Londoner, but 9 3/4 does not sound likely, even if you've never taken a train before.
The DaVinci Code creates esoteric pseudo-history with a pastiche of every Catholic conspiracy ever, and set in all the unrelated tourist locations the reader has seen on TV. Ancient treasure map? It's under Stonehenge of course! Knights Templar definitely built the Eiffel Tower to recharge Charlemagne's magic tiara (not actual plot points in a Dan Brown novel, but could be). It's not meant to be believable, rather it signals a globe-hopping treasure hunt where the clues are in plain sight (while being antagonized by esoteric secret societies who apparently don't want these un-hidden not-secrets to be discovered). The modern world is generously ret-conned to support the level of convoluted conspiracy in the plot.
You can signal elements that come from research because they read like a wikipedia infodump. Then you can communicate the fantastical by tying it to something that clearly does not exist. While some purists might object, most readers will happily indulge in historic-fantasy and fantastic-histories, as long as they are in on the game, and it supports the type of story they are reading.
Historic Fiction is not Cosplay
Readers want a story. If they wanted a textbook, they would read non-fiction.
In Fiction, conflict and character are more important than research and accuracy.  All the worldbuilding and exposition rules still apply, no matter how well-researched. Characters need to speak naturally. Descriptions must stay within the scope and understanding of the protagonist. The larger world is implied as the tip of a worldbuilding iceberg.
Many stories get around this by creating a timeless narrator, or a frame story where a modern-day researcher translates an eye-witness manuscript. These efforts to anchor the story in our reality can backfire by distancing the reader from the actual characters and conflict. It's hard to feel stakes for someone whose conflict ended 1000 years ago.
The story must 'play' in the reader's head. Every historically accurate but un-pronounceable location name has potential to throw the reader out of their suspension of disbelief.

If the original name of a historical place has been lost, you have a few options:

Avoid mentioning the name.

Pachacutec paused and looked up to the city. How beautiful it was!


Research what scholars assume might be its original name.
In the case of Machu Picchu, it has been suggested that the original name might have been Huayna Picchu, after the smaller peak nearby, or simply Picchu.

Pachacutec paused and looked up at Picchu. How beautiful it was!


Use what is known about the language of the original builders and make up a name.
According to some online dictionary, yuraq llaqta means "white city" in Quechua, the language spoken today by the descendants of the Inca.

Pachacutec paused and looked up at Yuraq Llaqta, the white city. How beautiful it was!

As you can see, I provided a translation of the name for the readers in the text. You can do that or not, according to your narrative style.


If you care for accuracy, you can ask an expert to verify the historic and/or linguistic plausibility of your names.

For some of the more popular languages there are online tools that help you create personal or place names. For example, https://ortsnamen.stadtkreation.de/ creates fictional German place names that (to my native ear) sound convincing. But don't forget that in the real world there are usually many places with the same or similar names. For example, there seem to be around 1700 villages named San José, and there are many towns and villages named San Some Saint or Santa Some Saint, so there is a pattern that you might need to consider if you want to name multiple places. The names in the German place name generator, while plausible, are all rather exotic and unique, even for a native German speaker. So if you need to name many places in your historical-fictional landscape, you might want to do a little research into place names in general as well as your historic place in particular.
